# How can I replace the value when a specific string is found in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I run a wrong SQL query and now I have to fix some things from the beginning.
In my wp_postmeta table there are two fields, meta_value and meta_key.

How can I replace the existing value of meta_key to **_tdomf_custom_permalink** on every row that the string **http://www.domain.com/?h** is found in meta_value using phpmyadmin SQL.

Secondly, how can I replace the http://www.domain.com/?h (in meta_value field) with another domain ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use update statements in SQL:

```
update wp_postmeta 
set meta_key = '_tdomf_custom_permalink' 
where meta_value = 'http://www.domain.com/?h'
```

to then replace the `http://www.domain.com/?h`:

```
update wp_postmeta 
set meta_value = 'http://www.yourdomain.com/?h' 
where meta_value = 'http://www.domain.com/?h'
```

Comment: have you tried not using % at the end of the searched string?  Or if you are using %, did you change the query to use the LIKE keyword?